# Metal railing mounted on composite decking and composite joists

Tags: support, decking, railing, composite

Is there a way to provide additional support to a metal railing mounted to a composite deck board? The long run of top railing sways a lot and will easily take off the screws in some time. The height is about 1 meter.

I can install material below the deck surface, but there's a waterproof roof directly under the joists. Existing joists were glued to the roof and I would prefer not to puncture the roof with with any fasteners.

[image: deck surface]
[image: post base]

**NOTE** : Added this for now on posts , seems to work okay [image]

Comment: Including a few pictures would sure help in understanding what your problem is.

Comment: Adding a stiffer top rail with a  couple of extra columns  equal distance from the corners, ( anchored below the top edge of the deck), is about the only way. Otherwise the railing is not suited for that use.

Comment: Typically railing gets mounted through the decking and into framing. By your description this is mounted to the deck board alone. Is that the case?

Comment: What does a typical post anchorage location look like from below? Can you get a picture that captures a few feet of the surrounding framing and circle the anchorage if it's not obvious in the picture? And fastening through the top of the deck boards into additional framing below is out of bounds right?

Comment: It is only mounted on the decking with screws , only proper support being on the wall as shown in the picture - post anchorage is just screws- added picture @popham

Comment: Can you get under there? Assuming typical wood framing, even a piece of blocking below wouldn't have much stiffness. Assuming that there's a rim board along the outside face, then I would install blocking a couple feet from that. Then I would span a 4"x4" or so between the rim board and the blocking directly below each post. At that point you could install fasteners through the deck boards to the 4"x4" and everything would be rock solid. If you can screw through the deck boards from above, then a similar solution is much easier. But it's all predicated on your framing.

Comment: below the decking is a fiberglass roof with no drilling/holes at all (so good to keep it that way), on top of it there are composite decking joist glued to the fireglass roof and the decking is screwed to the joists. That is all that is below the railing no other support structure.

Comment: Do you still have access to install a chunk of joist material below each post (parallel to the existing joists)? They wouldn't even need to be glued to the roof.

Comment: yes it will be possible to add the parallel joists below the post

Comment: Those are very artsy photos, but color film is _so_ inexpensive these days, that using it just makes sense...

Comment: Your last photo shows a significant part of the problem. The metal foot for the post has 2 screws going into some sort of bracket below the decking and 2 screws going into the decking itself. Your additional diagonal brace has a screw going into the decking. It should be moved farther away from where you took the pic so that it goes into whatever that is that's supporting the decking itself. This will give that screw _something_ more to bite into and give you more support.

Comment: @FreeMan, but I suspect that your advice doesn't generalize to the other post locations. In the background at the top of the image, I think I see another location with the post well out of alignment with the framing.

Comment: Well, that's an installation issue that should be addressed, too, @popham. Every post should go into _something_ below the deck. Counting on composite decking to hold up a railing is, well, asking for someone to fall off the deck. IMHO...

Answer (score -1):

For each post, install a 1m long or so chunk of joist material centered beneath it. It should run the same direction as existing joists and with its narrow edge pointed upward if possible. Install longer screws through the post and deck board and into the chunk of new joist material.

Without fasteners between the new chunk of joist and the other deck boards, I expect it will only have half of its stiffness potential. Still, though, deflecting the top rail in and out will now involve bending half of the deck boards over the new chunk instead of merely twisting the single board under the post. Fasten the deck boards down to the new chunk of joist to develop more stiffness. Adhesive the new joist chunks to the underlying roof to develop more stiffness.

Your deck's materials are unfamiliar to me, where I don't know how much withdrawal strength to expect for each fastener. I might install threaded inserts into the underside of the new joist chunks to receive bolts to achieve more withdrawal strength. Just something to keep in mind if the screw withdrawal strength turns out inadequate.

Comment: Thanks, yes this will help a bit but I think more of the movement is on the post itself, adding support to them helped but will add joist material below too as you suggested.

Comment: @xrcsblue, you inferred that the one free standing post in the middle of the short run of rail in the background of your first image was okay. This implied that there was nothing wrong with the post assembly's stiffness. I'm really confused how you decided that the long run posts were inadequate when that short run post was okay. Do you believe that different material thicknesses were used on that middle post versus the inadequate posts? Was that middle post braced like you've now braced an inadequate post? And did you add all of those fasteners down to the joists in your last image?

Comment: They were the same posts but the smaller ones were bolted to the wall at one end so the top was supported firmly. The fastners are bolted to the decking decking at bottom, so now the post is supported by two different deck boards.

Comment: @xrcsblue, your braces brought an additional deck board into the system for stiffness, where I suspect that's where most additional stiffening came from. Assuming 11 gauge posts and 3/16" base plates, I computed the post stiffness on a perfectly rigid foundation as about 3/8" horizontal deflection for 25# of horizontal load. That feels pretty stiff to my intuition for a railing, but your brace should have taken that down to less than 1/8" on a perfectly rigid foundation. If you're the one who has been installing those board fasteners like that, then buy a countersink bit for your drill.